# Page currently being edited by another user notification?

Tags: admin, workflow

Any thoughts on how I could let  users know when they go to a page in the backend that/if another user is currently editing that page? I don't need it to lock editing, just to present a notice that it's being looked at/edited by someone else﻿

Answer (score 1):

It would definitely have to be a plugin, but I'm not sure the right events are available for a plugin to pull it off right now.

Seems like there would need to be at least two that need to be created.  Some `onDisplayEntry` event that gets fired as soon as an entry page is viewed and another `onEditEntry` event that gets fired over AJAX as soon as any field value changes.